# Complex query mongoose - embedded documents array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to execute a query for getting all "group" documents that have the userId in there array of users.

I've tried several different ways of query, but I always get an empty array.

What am I doing wrong?

group.js

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Group = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [{
        userId: {
            type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
            ref: 'users',
            required: true
        },
        userType: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        userStatus: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('group', Group);
```

groupController.js

```
exports.getUserGroups = function (req, res) {
    Group.find({
        "users.userid": "req.user._id"
    }, function (err, groups) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(groups);
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator

```
db.collection.find({
  "users.userId": {
    $in: [
      req.user._id
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work, the $in operator uses an array. But the problem is that the users is an array of objects. I tried users[0] but it also doesn't work.

Comment: `$in` operator is also used to find the matched document from the collection... and It does work... Did you check it

Comment: Thanks this works! I had another problem - mongoose adds "s" at the end of the collection! and it was trying to fetch the data from a collection that doesn't exist. That's why no matter what I did, I always got an empty array.

Comment: This is a confusing answer because `$in` isn't required for this query.

Comment: @JohnnyHK might be `$in` doesn't required here but atleast it works and better than a typo answer

Comment: My concern is that this is a common point of confusion where people think they need to use `$in` because their field is an array, but that's not true.

Comment: @JohnnyHK please have a look at **on this page section**  [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)... And have a look at three points 1)`Use the $in Operator to Match Values`
2)`Use the $in Operator to Match Values in an Array`
3)`Use the $in Operator with a Regular Expression`... And I think first one is your confusion's answer

Answer (score 0):

Field names are case-sensitive, so `"users.userid"` should be `"users.userId"` instead:

```
Group.find({
    "users.userId": "req.user._id"
}, ...
```

Comment: What changes you made here?  What case sensitive?

Comment: If you thought of typo here then you should have commented instead of answering... Such answers doesn't make sense at all

Comment: @DarkKnight Perhaps, but we're supposed to avoid answering questions in comments.

Comment: But typo is not an answer from any point of view... Typo is just a typo where the people miss something and can be explained in comments...